# No comprendo en como sale del primer bucle while que se declara en true

Tags: solidity

muy buenas noches a todos, me encuentro aprendiendo solidity. Me gustaría saber en cómo es que se sale de este bucle, no comprendo cuando la condición del primer while pasa a ser false para salir del bucle. Les dejo el código.

```
   // Devolver el siguiente número primo, a partir del numero que se le introduce a la función
  // un número primo es aquel que es divisible entre 1 y el mismo
function siguientePrimo(uint _p) public pure returns(uint){
    uint contador = _p + 1;
    while(true){
        // Comprobamos si contador es primo
        uint aux = 2;
        bool primo = true;
        while(aux < contador){
            if (contador % aux == 0){
                primo = false;
                break;
            }
            aux++;
        }
        if(primo == true){
            break;
        }
        contador++;
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no conozco este lenguaje, pero ahi hay un break dentro del if... eso no corta el while?

Comment: La condición nunca pasa a ser false, simplemente la palabra reservada break es la que se encarga de salir del bucle, rompiendo la ejecución.